# How to show GregoriaCalender backing form object on HTML input tag

Tags: java, jsp

I am new at spring and jsp. I had a form backing object GregorianCalender as *deadlineDate*.
How can I show *deadlineDate* as a default value of input tag (date type) in jsp.
I tried:

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${project.deadlineDate.time}" />
```

and it print out: 2016-04-17

but when I put it all in *value* attribute of another tag, like below, it's not work:

```
<form:input id="deadlineDate" path="deadlineDate" type="date"
                        class="form:input-large" value='<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${project.deadlineDate.time}" />'/>
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Here is my taglib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
```